# how do you install the module commands like ins mod,etc

Tags: macos, terminal, kernel, insmod

I have to load a kernel module to run a program. I searched online and found out I need to use commands like insmod, etc to do that. But the command doesn't seem to be installed in my laptop. I am working on a Mac. I tried running as a admin by sudo command. tried all commands like whereis, location and find still dont get an ans. Can anyone please help. If there is an alternative to load a kernel module to run some program files on, alternative will be appreciated.

Error: You may need to load a kernel module to support tap.

Answer (score 0):

OS X uses a completely different kernel extension model than Linux. If you have a compatible kernel extension, you can use [`kextload(8)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/kextload.8.html) to load it.

Comment: I will try and let you know the result.